# Boosting elastic aggregation result

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, boost, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an elastic index for `product`s, each product has `Brand` attribution and I "have to" create an `aggregation` that returns `Brand`s of the products.

My Sample Query:

```
GET /products/product/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myFancyFilter": {
      "filter": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Brand",
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 236952,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "myFancyFilter": {
      "doc_count": 236952,
      "inner": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 139267,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Brand1",
            "doc_count": 3144
          },
          {
            "key": "Brand2",
            "doc_count": 1759
          },
          {
            "key": "Brand3",
            "doc_count": 1737
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfect for me. Elastic sorts buckets according to `doc_count`, however I would like to manipulate the bucket order in result. For example, assume that I have `Brand5` and I want to increment its order to #2. I want result coming in order Brand1, Brand5 and Brand3.

If it was not in an `aggregation`, but in a `query`, I could use `function_score`, but now, I don't have an idea. Any clues?

Comment: If you have another field that you can use in a metric sub-aggregation, you could leverage that sub-aggregation in order to change the way the top-level aggregation is sorted.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the top-hits aggregation?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html This way you could control the order of the results using a custom script or some other field.

Comment: Thanks I will try these solutions today.

Comment: @Val what kind of metric aggregation you mean? As we want to order filtered aggregations, only option we see is scripted metric aggregation, am I right?

Comment: What other field do you have that would make `Brand5` bubble up to the second bucket?

Comment: @Val it is dynamic and should come from request, I mean, request wants `Brand5` to bubble up to the 2nd order and it is not related to any field value. Something like (pseudocode) `"map_script" : "return doc.Brand.value == 'Brand5' ? 2 : null"`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to *define your own sorting definition* and that to be applied in `aggregation` in `elasticsearch`. I've been able to come up with a solution by renaming the aggregation terms in below manner:

- `Brand1` to `a_Brand1`
- `Brand5` to `b_Brand5`
- `Brand3` to `c_Brand3`

And then apply sorting on the terms so that sorting happens lexicographically.

*Of course this may not be the exact or the best solution but I felt this can help*.

Below is the query that I've used. Please note that my field name is `brand` and it is a `multifield` and I'm using the field `brand.keyword`.

```
POST testdataindex/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "myFancyFilter":{  
         "filter":{  
            "match_all":{  

            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "inner":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "script":{  
                     "lang":"painless",
                     "inline":"if(params.newNames.containsKey(doc['brand.keyword'].value)) { return params.newNames[doc['brand.keyword'].value];} return null;",
                     "params":{  
                        "newNames":{  
                           "Brand1":"a_Brand1",
                           "Brand5":"b_Brand5",
                           "Brand3":"c_Brand3"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "order":{  
                     "_term":"asc"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've created a sample data with brand names `Brand1`, `Brand3` and `Brand5` and below how the results would appear. Note the change in the term names.

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 8,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "myFancyFilter": {
      "doc_count": 8,
      "inner": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "a_Brand1",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "b_Brand5",
            "doc_count": 4
          },
          {
            "key": "c_Brand3",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!